# How to allways run the same file using 'script' in 'Atom'

Tags: python, flask, atom-editor

I'm using `Atom IDE` with the `script` package to run A flask application in python. 
My folder looks like this:

```
- my_flask_app.py
- css/
    - main.css
- templates/
    - base.html
    - index.html
...
```

So if the `my_flask_app.py` is the file open in the editor when I run, everything works grate.
But if this `index.html` is the current open file in the editor it will just try to run the file itself and not the flask app. How can I do it so no matter what is the current open file it will allways run the python file? 
Edit:
As response to @ali-beyit, This is the Configure Run Options I entered:
[image: Configure Run Options]
And this is the output I got:

```
'"python my_flask_app.py"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.033s]
```

Comment: use the command `python my_flask_app.py`

Comment: do you have python configured as an environment variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `python my_flask_app.py` isn't a command. It should work using `python` as the command, given that it's exposed in the PATH [environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351). You would then put the file-name `my_flask_app.py` as command-argument.